# get header of a selected gridview column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm making a simple web application in C#. The site which I'm working on contains a GridView. The GridView shows the data from an Oracle SQL data table.

Now I want to have filtering options for my table. But I want to make it very easy to switch through the columns and I want to make it possible to filter and maybe sort each column for itself.

I already made a TextBox which instantly filters a specific column. But I want to have the User to select the column. My idea is to have the user selecting a column and then he only has to write his criteria into the TextBox.

My main problem at the moment is to figure out how to make the user able to select a column and get its index/header-text.

For instance: I want to get the index/header-text  if the user wants to filter/sort the column and somehow selected it.

I'm new on asp.net and I don't really know how to realize this. I've searched a lot to find any solutions, but there isn't much about this.

I used this for my filtering method (works):

```
dt = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: If a user can select multiple columns to sort on, how do you define the sort order? Do you always sort by lowest index first? By which were selected first?

Comment: @sr28 These are good points, but actually this is not very important for me at the moment, because I can figure this out by myself later. My main problem is to get the index of a column, which the user wishes to filter/sort. At the moment I don't know how to realize it.

Comment: It's important if you want to sort by multiple columns. The design for allowing a user to filter or sort on 1 columns would most likely be different to that of allowing someone to filter on multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

1. For sort by column specify inside the tag of the Gridview:

> 

```
      AllowSorting="true">

  </asp:gridview>
```

2. For Getting the header text of any column:

   Gridview.Columns[i].HeaderText
3. No possible to filter by columns with a checkbox on the header

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer. Is there another solution for the third point? It has not to be checkBoxes. Is there no way to solve this? I want it to be possible to filter each column. For instance if I want to search for the name Paul, then it should filter the table accordingly to this criteria.

Comment: I would make a dropdown list with the column names beside the search textbox. That way they can select the criteria they want to search on and you don't have to worry about what column they clicked. Either that or you could do a general search box that searches every column for what they type.

Comment: I am agree with @MarcieKaiser this is a common technique, and usually people use 2 dropdowns if the need to order by more than one column. Also for search criteria i like the idea of open textbox so when you search for that criteria on your sql search you can use LIKE in all columns that match that criteria. something like SELECT * FROM user WHERE firtname like '%searchcriteria%' OR lastname like '%searchcriteria%'